# Windows Phone 8.1/10 App Developement

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, win-universal-app

So my current problem is that I have to develop a windows phone app that should be able to run on windows phone 8.1 and windows phone 10. As I am new to the windows phone world, I would like to know what is the best way to achieve this?

After reading a few entries I have learned that there is visual studio 2015 to develop windows phone 8.1 apps and that windows phone 10 apps are developed as universal apps. Is it possible to also run universal apps on Windows 8.1 that I developed for Windows 10? (I guess there are functionalities new to windows phone 10 that are not available in 8.1)

Comment: in vs2015 build windows phone 8.1 app which will run on both windows phone 8.1 and windows 10 mobile, using windows phone 8.1 sdk

Comment: develop the 8.1 App in VS2013 (in 2015 8.1 app dev tools are optional components during setup), this works for phone 8.1 and Win10 mobile.

Comment: @ShubhamSahu
Thank you for the reply; so if I develop the 8.1 app it will also show the app in the windows phone 10 store?  
And would this also work if I build a universal app for 8.1?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you for the reply; so if I develop the 8.1 app it will also show the app in the windows phone 10 store? And would this also work if I build a universal app for 8.1?

Comment: @alisheikh yesss! Only difference is availability of api and tools but some tools or api available in wp8.1 which is not available in uwp and some api and tools available in uwp but not available in wp8.1 but if you want to targe both version of device OS then definitely go with wp8.1 development you can use max vs2015 because you can develop for wp8.1 in vs2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ShubhamSahu the question is answered.
It is possible to execute/download WP 8.1 Apps on WP 10.